# “Tizzarget Acquizzired”; What's the deal with the Z's when imitating divers?

Tags: accent, nautical-terms

When imitating scuba divers, especially "old-timey" ones, extra Z's or "izz"es get added to the middle of words. What is the origin of this?

I have heard this in a few older shows, including the original Scooby Doo series, and now most recently in How I Met Your Mother, where Barney Stinson modifies "Target Acquired" to become "Tizzarget Aquizzired", while wearing a diving suit.

Comment: I think it's just a kind of "speech impediment / affectation" popularised by voiceovers for cinema/TV cartoon characters. For example, [*Sylvester the Cat's trademark exclamation is "Sufferin' succotash!", which is said to be a minced oath of "Suffering Savior"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_the_Cat). We don't generally let children laugh at people with disabilities today, but speech impediments in Cartoonland seem to be exempt from that principle. Also native speakers of certain *specific* languages may not normally be able to easily enunciate certain *English* phonemes.

Comment: (***Also*** - your diction might be characteristically affected in this way if you're trying to speak while keeping your teeth firmly clamped on the mouthpiece of a ***snorkel***, for example. I don't have a snorkel to hand, so I'm not in a position to test this theory out more fully! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm no diver, but might the speaker not also be emitting bubbles while talking?

Comment: @Kate: I was being a bit "tichy" ("tongue-in-cheeky") when I said I don't have a snorkel! Just clench your teeth together and try to speak without introducing unwanted sibilance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't disputing what you say, I just thought that if the speaker was underwater the sound would also be affected by bubbles.

Comment: @KateBunting: [Lord Smythington and his butler Waddle:](https://www.reddit.com/r/dadjokes/comments/aw7nmz/lord_smythington_and_his_butler_waddle/) *Sir I though I heard you say “What about a water bottle Waddle?”* You're obviously thinking more about "hubble bubble, toil and trouble" assonance than the sibilance associated with speaking through gritted teeth!

Comment: ...warming to my theme, I just found this on Twitter: [*It is a particular genius of the English language that word “**congratulations**” may be said through **gritted teeth**. The **sibilant hiss** it creates makes the word all the sweeter to the ear...*](https://twitter.com/lordgrimdark/status/727942664868483073)

Comment: This sounds like *iz*-infixation — a sort of pig latin popularized in hiphop culture but possibly traced back to a similar sounding *-eas-* infix that was used by carnival barkers. None of this has anything to do with scuba diving though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you've ever seen Monty Python's hilarious *Life of Brian*, you'll know that it wasn't just CartoonLand that made fun of speech impediments back in the day. "Your father was a *w*oman?" "No, a Roman. [gets slapped] OW!"

Comment: @TinfoilHat: [Abso-b████y-lutely!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt22yWYX64w) Though I agree with Tom Scott there that most *native* Anglophones are never explicitly taught anything about "**infixation**" because in English it's almost entirely restricted to infixing ***swear-words***. Nevertheless, practically all native speakers understand ***exactly*** how to follow the rules (we all know that **Ab-b████y-solutely** isn't "valid", for example), which sometimes makes me wonder why we pay people to teach grammar and syntax to native speakers in the first place!